# seting focus angucomplete-alt

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using the directive [angucomplete-alt](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt) and I'm facing an issue to set the focus on input as soon as the page loads, but I don't know how to do it and the solutions that I have found seem very hacky.

**Example code:**

```
<angucomplete-alt id="ex2"
              placeholder="Search people"
              pause="300"
              selected-object="selectedPerson"
              local-data="people"
              local-search="localSearch"
              title-field="firstName,surname"
              description-field="twitter"
              image-field="pic"
              minlength="1"
              input-class="form-control form-control-small"
              match-class="highlight" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know this directive, but it seems you can't set focus on input without some hacky. I made some searchs on their github and I found the same [issue](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt/issues/188) there and there is a possible solution that can solve your problem.

Here's is a snippet working:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['angucomplete-alt']);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
   $timeout(function() {
     var searchInput = document.getElementById('ex2_value');
     searchInput.focus();
   }, 0);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angucomplete-alt/2.4.1/angucomplete-alt.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <angucomplete-alt id="ex2"
          placeholder="Search people"
          pause="300"
          selected-object="selectedPerson"
          local-data="people"
          local-search="localSearch"
          title-field="firstName,surname"
          description-field="twitter"
          image-field="pic"
          minlength="1"
          input-class="form-control form-control-small"
          match-class="highlight" />
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: One last Question, i tried to apply in 2 inputs, the only the first focus is applied, is there a reason? ex: $timeout(function() {
                var searchInputFirst = document.getElementById('first_value');
                var searchInputSecond = document.getElementById('second_value');
                searchInputFirst.focus();
                searchInputSecond.focus();

            }, 0);

Comment: **1st. question:** `$timeout` is just a service to set a delay to do something, you can get more explanation in docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout. On other hand, here it's unuseful, unless you want to put a little delay to set focus. **2nd. question:** you can only set focus on one element at a time.